# Strategies for controlling access to Linux namespaced Unix domain sockets

Tags: android, ipc, android-security, unix-socket, linux-namespaces

Android SDK provides LocalSocket objects for IPC over Unix Domain Sockets, but does so using Linux abstract namespaces. As such, any process can bind to the server socket, where standard Unix sockets generally require read/write permission to access the sockets file descriptor. I can see many vulnerabilities that can arise from this and was wondering what strategies are used to prevent access from unintended sources as well as means of securing data over the sockets.

Please note that the question is specifically about LocalSockets. Using other Android IPC mechanisms might solve the problem of unwanted access but sadly are not an option in my case. However, passing some form of credentials over such mechanisms can be possible if it would secure the LocalSocket.

Comment: "Using other Android IPC mechanisms might solve the problem of unwanted access but sadly are not an option in my case" -- why not? What is `LocalSocket` giving you that, say, a `ParcelableFileDescriptor` does not?

Comment: @CommonsWare Access to Unix Sockets within native services. ParcelableFileDescriptor isn't available in native C/C++ apis from what I have seen, same for other mechanisms (Binder, etc)

Comment: Binder is most certainly available to C/C++ code. Much of Android is implemented in C/C++, and most of Android's IPC is powered by Binder.

Comment: @CommonsWare yes, Binder is available as can bee seen in linux/binder.h but is undocumented and is generally inaccessible from what I've seen. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that [Karim Yaghmour's "Embedded Android" book](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920021094.do) gets into Binder, as do some of his conference presentations. [This repo](https://github.com/gburca/BinderDemo) claims to have a demo of using Binder from C++, though it's a bit old. [Here is some documentation](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/tools/aidl/+/brillo-m10-dev/docs/aidl-cpp.md).